# Android Holding back button freezes my UI

Tags: android, android-camera, zxing, barcode-scanner

I have an app I am implementing with the Capture Activity project of ZXING.  Everything works well, but I have found a quirky issue.  If I click a button on my interface to initiate the scan, it switches to the zxing scanner.  If I hit the back button, it exits - no issues at all.  I stumbled upon the fact that if - instead of "tapping" the back button, I hold it down just a tad too long, the app goes back, but nothing on the UI can be tapped.

I have logging in my class that shows the same EXIT is happening whether I tap or hold, so it's odd.  At the point that the app is "frozen" if I tap and hold the home button, then slide it up (as if I were going to enter google search) but then slide it back down (as if I changed my mind about google search) then the UI is no longer frozen, and I can again tap buttons.  No errors appear in the stack  or logcat.  Here are some code snippets.  Hoping someone has advice!

```
// This is what is called when I click my "scan" button.
public void menuScanMember(View view) {
    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
        intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE,PRODUCT_MODE");
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is what is called when the intent is exited (either with back button or with a scan)

```
//In the same activity you'll need the following to retrieve the results:
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == 0) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            p_strScanMemId = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
            String strId = getMemberByMemberId(db, p_strScanMemId);

            if (strId != null && !("".equalsIgnoreCase(strId))) {
                // If found, send to member info landing page
                Intent detailIntent = new Intent(this, MemberDetail.class);
                detailIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, p_strScanMemId);
                startActivity(detailIntent);
            } else {
                // If not found, ask user if they want to create the member account now.
                createYesNoDialog("Member Not Found.  Register Now?");
            }

        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Log.v("CANCELLED CANCELLELD", "RESULT CANCELLED");
            // Nothing to do here - we'll just exit the activity
        }
    }
}
```

- The "cancelled" statement shows up in my log regardless if I tap or if I hold the back button.

Comment: When you hold the back button down, does any phone sliders appear to the left or right?

Comment: Instead of getting the result back in `onActivityResult` method, would it not be better to process the result via the `onNewIntent` method in an `Activity` since you're passing an extra ("SCAN_MODE") back with the `Intent`?

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a good solution.  I looked through the code that comes with the CaptureActivity code.  There is a onKeyDown handler with a switch that looks for the back button.  I ended up overriding onKeyUp and moved the back button detection to that method, so the intent no longer exits if back button is held down, only when it's let up.